# Line numbers in Word mess up pdf rendering

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office

I'm desperately trying to add line numbers to a Word document. Everything looks fine ("word 1" and "word 2" pictures) but, on print or export, every line containing a line number is overlaid with a white box for ~3/4 of the page width, resulting in a broken pdf (or print)  ("pdf 2" picture). The lines with no numbers are ok ("pdf 1" picture).

I've tried to change all sorts of fonts and paragraph settings, but it is broken and in three hours I couldn't find a solution. The same problem appears on all Mac and Windows machines I've tried to export the docx to pdf from.

Do someone ever had a similar problem?

Here the album with all pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvtRR.jpg

Comment: Works fine for a trivial document. Please post an example (short) document. What is your Office version?

Comment: Reduced version of the culprit: https://transfer.sh/%28/AQL81/broken-word.docx%29.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations - you have found a bug in Microsoft Word!

I have tried printing your document using : Physical printer, Adobe PDF,
Foxit Reader PDF Printer, Microsoft Print to PDF and even Word's Save As PDF.

The results were always the same. The inescapable conclusion is that the problem
is with Word and not with any of the printer drivers that I tried.

I then downloaded and installed an Office alternative suite, namely
[FreeOffice](https://www.freeoffice.com/en/download/applications),
free for home and business use. The result when printed to PDF were perfect:

[image]

You may signal the bug to Microsoft using the Feedback Hub via the Start menu.

In the meantime, you will need another Office suite than Microsoft's for
generating the PDF.
In addition to FreeOffice, you will find other alternatives on
[Microsoft Office Suite Alternatives and Similar Software - AlternativeTo.net](https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-office-suite/).

Comment: I figured it is a bug, I solved it by sending it over to a friend who has an older version. Gg Microsoft